# Limiting MySQL User to connect from Second interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, iptables, web-server

The web server and the MySQL servers have a second interface on a network with no public internet access.

How can a MySQL user be restricted to connect only from within the private network and through that second interface?

For a start, I have disabled `bind-address` in `my.cnf`

```
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0
```

Can this be more restrictive? Can MYSQL users be restricted to connect only from the second interface?

Answer (score 2):

You can give bind-address the ip of your second interface. For example:

```
bind-address = 192.168.220.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict access to the MySQL by iptables, for e.g.

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

Also you can restrict mysql user himself

```
mysql> grant all privileges on test_db.* to test_user@'192.168.%' identified by '1234567';
```